# Electron : how to manage user auth in main and renderer process?

Tags: electron, supabase, supabase-js

I am building an Electron App with this user flow:
1- User logs in
2- Enters local db credentials
3- App fetch local db every X minutes
4- App sends data to somewhere else logged in as the user

Since I use Supabase and want to use their client SDK as much as possible :
I authenticate the user twice : in the renderer process and also in the main process. On login, I send an IPC message to the main process with the credentials and request a login again.
This way I can use supabaseClient in my main and renderer process.

At first I thought it was a good idea but I read that http requests should be done on the renderer process for network security purpose (eg in a company network).
Furthermore, the requests are split all around the code base and it is a pain to find anything as there is no logical ordering.

In short, how should I manage user auth?
How should the app be designed (what process does what)?

Any additional insight is also appreciated!

Comment: Check out this tutorial on how to use Auth0 in electron: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-electron-applications-with-openid-connect-and-oauth-2/